# Jenkins 2.1: ERROR: Step ‘Post build task’ aborted @ java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

After upgrading Jenkins and Plugins recently, the Post Build task randomly aborts with an exception as shown bellow. What is causing it and how can it be fixed?

**Software Version:**

Jenkins ver. 2.103;
Hudson Post build task v1.8

**Error Message (printed to Jenkins console):**

```
15:29:38 ERROR: Step ‘Post build task’ aborted due to exception: 
15:29:38 java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
15:29:38    at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:281)
15:29:38    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:339)
15:29:38    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
15:29:38    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
15:29:38    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
15:29:38    at java.io.BufferedReader.read1(BufferedReader.java:212)
15:29:38    at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:286)
15:29:38    at hudson.Util.loadFile(Util.java:199)
15:29:38    at hudson.model.Run.getLog(Run.java:1953)
15:29:38    at hudson.plugins.postbuildtask.PostbuildTask.perform(PostbuildTask.java:99)
15:29:38    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
15:29:38    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
15:29:38    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps    (AbstractBuild.java:690)
15:29:38    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
15:29:38    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
15:29:38    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1752)
15:29:38    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
15:29:38    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
15:29:38    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is related to [JENKINS-49112](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-49112).

The problem is that Jenkins cannot handle the charset when reading the console output during runtime. The breaking changes are reverted and the problem will be resolved in 2.104.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18660654)

Comment: Edited to provide more context.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll wait for 2.104 then.

Comment: The error is not seen after upgrading to Jenkins 2.104

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Jenkins was trying to parse a .yml file which included an `ä`

Removing that solved it.